# Google Polymer - how to add content to Neon elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

## The playground

http://labs.recgr.com/polymer-dev/test1.html

#### My goal

I've managed to replicate [this](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/neon-animation?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=neon-animated-pages) animation, but I need it to have content as well (text and images).

#### The Problem

**Inserting content** - I've been experimenting with adding just text for now, and I cannot get it working.

#### What I've tried

**Adding content directly to div circle div container** in *circles-page.html*, it doesn't work properly.

```
<div class="circle">test</div>
```

Result: [image]

**Getting position with jQuery**, on *circles-page.html* (at the bottom of the page):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var sq_pos = $(".square");
    console.log(sq_pos.position());
});
</script>
```

.. and then using that to make an invisible div above that, to display content.

Result: `undefined` (in Chrome Console)

**I also tried** using jQuery to add content once Dom is ready, but it didn't work, nor did various properties inside Polymer object I've tried (that I've seen on documentation).

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Polymer's layout system to achieve this easily.

To lay out all the circles horizontally, apply `horizontal layout` to the *parent div*. Then you just need to use `center-center horizontal layout` on the *child div* to center the text.

```
<div class="horizontal layout">
  <div class="circle center-center horizontal layout">test</div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

You can read more about this [iron-flex-layout](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/flex-layout) from here.

Comment: Sir, you're a savior. I already read pretty much all documentation at https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide, and I was still like "wth.." - I had no idea that one should manipulate layout via iron flex. Thank you.

Comment: @HouseMdd I am still learning :), from their elements page, online documents, GitHub and YouTube channels (mainly Rob's).